# Provisioning Profile not getting added in Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, provisioning-profile, ipa

I have downloaded a distribution Provisioning Profile. Previously in xcode 4.2 I used to double click on the Provisioning profile and it used to appear in the organizer of Xcode.However this is not happening in case of Xcode 4.6.when I double click it doesn't get added nor does it appear in the code signing option. I have successfully added Certificate which can be seen in keychain.

Comment: I do not have Maveriks or Xcode 5.I m running on OSX version 10.7.5 which does not support Xcode 5.I don't want to upgrade to mavericks as it would require time to download and install.I have only 1 Xcode installed. I was able to add it before. Please suggest if there is any other way to do it in Xcode 4.6.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way going forward is to stay up to date with Apple's latest software. And with Mavericks being free... At some point in the near future, Apple will require App Store submission from Xcode 5. You also need it to support iOS 7, something you really should be going.

Answer (score 3):

When you download the certificate, drag it from the Downloads folder to the Xcode icon in the dock. Might I also suggest updating Xcode to 5.0.2? It includes automatic provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it opens with the desired Xcode. Usually if you have 2 Xcodes installed the file opens with only one of them. Make sure you right click on the profile file -> open with -> appropriate xcode. If that's not the case, just try in the organizer to click import and select the profile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, then I'm experiencing the same issue with Xcode 4 after updating to Mavericks.
Since then double-clicking on a provisioning profile doesn't add it to Xcode automatically. 
You need to drag'n'drop a file to Xcode organizer.